# Hair in unity not working well with paritcale system

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

My problem is :
I made a character in blender with hair as particale system and when i get it to unity its not import it good at all.
Can i make hair for my character inside unity? or ?
Please help me.
Ty.
[Blender - how its need to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLYVg.jpg)
[Unity - how it showen..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rmwN.png)

Comment: Can you provided picture when in blender and when in unity?

Comment: i provied 2 images now, one from blender and one from unity .

Comment: Have you tried other format?